# I am having difficulty displaying a string from a value from my ViewModel using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I have a list:

```
public List<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
```

How would I display one piece of information from one object within that list using Razor syntax?

I want to do something like:

```
@Html.Display(MyModel.Select(o => o.objectId = selectedObjectVal).FirstOrDefault().TextThatNeedsDisplayed)
```

But that does not compile.  How would I properly display the information I want?

When I use the updated code above (retrieved from an answer below) I get the following error:  CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'grade' and no extension method 'grade' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). The IntelliSense is giving me options of "Compare To" "Equals" "GetHashCode" etc. . .

---

Update:

If I do a .ToString()) at the end in place of "TextThatNeedsDisplayed" (and change from @Html.Display to @Html.Raw) it returns the data that it is searching by - literally what is stored at "o.objectId = selectedObjectVal" .  I don't know why this is - shouldn't it be trying to turn the entire MyModel into a string?  Still not showing TextThatNeedsDisplayed.

Comment: You have `=` where you want `==`. Is this just wrong in the question text here, or is that the actual problem in your code?

Comment: Big facepalm.  I spent about an hour on this. . .  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your Model is a list of (View)Models you could access a property of one model in many ways.

if the list is the model for your razor view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[0].TextThatNeedsDisplayed)
```

or just select one object from your list:

```
@Html.Display(MyModel.First().TextThatNeedsDisplayed)
```

Hope I understood your question right.